# Using a directive multiple times containing kendo elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

I have the following directive

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])


.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return{
    template:'<div k-on-resize="resized()" kendo-splitter k-orientation="horizontal"id="splitter"><div><div kendo-grid="myGrid" options="mainGridOptions"></div></div><div><p>{{hello}}</p></div></div></div></div>',
    scope:{},
    controller:function($scope,$element){
      $scope.hello = "Hello from Controller!";


      $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                }
            },
        columns: [{
                template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                                "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                            "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
                field: "ContactName",
                title: "Contact Name",
            }, {
                field: "ContactTitle",
                title: "Contact Title"
            }, {
                field: "CompanyName",
                title: "Company Name"
            }, {
                field: "Country",
            }]
      };

      $scope.resized = function(){

        if($("#splitter .k-pane:first").css("width") < '350px'){
        $scope.myGrid.hideColumn("ContactName");
        $scope.myGrid.hideColumn("Country");
        }else{
        $scope.myGrid.showColumn("ContactName");
        $scope.myGrid.showColumn("Country"); 
        }
      };
    }

  }
  })
```

Basically just creating a kendo Grid with some data and using a kendo splitter, the grid comes on the left side of the splitter. I have attached a event on kendo splitter where if the width is < 300px the grid will hide some columns.

This directive works perfectly if placed used only once on the a page but will not work if used multiple times. How to resolve this ??

Comment: According to this Kendo already has Angular integration out of the box? 
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/angularjs-and-kendo-ui-framework-integration
Unless i have the wrong product? If not the `elem` or `element` object provided in yoru link method Is a JQuery object representing the directive. Could you not get the id from that? Or call the Kendo methods directly off it?

Comment: @ste2425 Yes it does , basically I'm making a email module directive that implements kendo dropdown and kendo editor. Now i want to call the kendo dropdown functions via the directive...

Comment: Can you not then add the dropdown directive to the element you wish in your custom email directives template? Otherwise use the element object in your link method to to manipulate the DOM and call the Kendo methods against? If you could provide more code of your custom directive it may be of help.

Comment: @ste2425 Updated the question , let me know if its clearer

Comment: sorry but im still not entirely with you. Are you saying you couldn't have multiple instances of your custom directive on the same page because of the properties of your scope you bind to the kendo directives? Are your custom directives not using isolated scopes? If they are each whill have its own instance so each won't conflict with the other. They won't share the same scope then they could be re-used in the same page.

Comment: @ste2425 have added the specific code , let me know if any further clarification is needed

Comment: Perhaps this fiddle is what your looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/L6vSX/50/ I looked through the docs and was unable to find anywhere doing `kendo-grid="myGrid"`. It does not appear to return or set a reference to it self. I couldn't find anywhere in the docs saying you can show/hide columns through angular. So you have to use the $element and traverse the DOM and use the jquery way instead. Edit: the `resized()` has `$timeout` to call the code in the next digest cycle giving kendo time to perform the actual re-size. I got glitch'y behavior without.